# ListFragment List staying in the middle of the page

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having issues with my listFragment staying in the middle of the page. Like this:

http://i.imgur.com/60ZpelK.jpg

I'm using a listview in my xml document like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Which i'm pretty sure has no issues. But my Java i'm guessing is a little more dubious as i'm still learning.

```
public class menu_4_fragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    View rootview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Basic way of implementing title, perhaps a better method should be used if found
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Settings");

        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu4_layout, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Brings the data from XML to view
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Settings_strings, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Can you guys see anything that's potential causing this issue? Or perhaps what would be a better way to implement this list frag? I'm having a bit of an issue implementing this in the first place as i've already got a fragmentation from my navigation drawer and most tutorials don't show how to implement a listview beyond that.

Thanks guys.

Comment: set height to `match_parent` and remove `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` ,  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your XML layout clearly says that you want your `ListView` to reside in the middle. Try changing to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` if you want it to kind of start from the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these two lines

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```